# How to get count of total entry for the week in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime column which is the `signed_in` column, i need to get the total count of entries in the database every new week but the code below returns 0. I need help to acheive this please.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS _total 
FROM FirstTimer 
WHERE MONTH(Signed_in) = DATEPART(WEEK,getdate());
```

the image link is the result of the sql query but how can i get only the `_total` column

[image]

Comment: Edit the question add some sample date & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Where month = week? That doesn't look right.

Comment: You will not recieve any records, because you are comparing `WEEK` with `MONTH`. Currently we are on week 33 wilch will never be valid for any month value. You have to change your where clause to `WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, signed_in) = DATEPART(WEEK, getdate())`

Comment: If you have questions about a particular answer then it is better to use the comments below that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seems want :

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, Signed_in) , COUNT(*) AS _total 
FROM FirstTimer
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, signed_in) = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, Signed_in);
```

Edit : If you want only `_total` then you can do :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [_total] 
FROM FirstTimer
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, signed_in) = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE());
```

Comment: And if you only want the total column:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS _total 
FROM FirstTimer
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, signed_in) = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, Signed_in);`

Comment: @Martin. . . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of compare week numbers, you can filter records that greater than the first day of the week. Because if you compare week numbers you also need to compare years.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 

SELECT COUNT(*) AS _total 
FROM FirstTimer 
WHERE 
 Signed_in > SELECT CAST( DATEADD( DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) ,GETDATE()) AS DATE )
```